# Smarty caching requiring extra refresh

Tags: php, caching, smarty, delay

This is a peculiar issue that might have to do with the environment. Basically I did not have this problem running Smarty under Windows, but when migrating to a Ubuntu Vagrant box, I get this weird latency:

1. When refreshing the page, all the variables, var_dumps, etc. from my index.php do get rendered properly.
2. The template, however, does not refresh until second or sometimes even third refresh.
3. I have tried editing the files both outside and inside vagrant with the same results.
4. `$smarty->setCaching(Smarty::CACHING_OFF);` appears to have effect on the result.

I have set `setCompileCheck(true)` in my code. I notice that upon refreshing a page, the templates under `templates_c` do get refreshed. However, the file getting served to the browser is at least one iteration behind.

I could easily verify this by having a template with text "A", then adding a "B", refreshing, adding a "C" refreshing etc. Each refresh was one iteration behind so after adding the C, I got "AB", and the refresh after that showed "C".

Logic would dictate this is a smarty template issue, because adding to the output in my `index.php` appears to instantly reflect my changes (except to the templates), thus it is not `apache2` caching that's causing this.

Clearing all template data on every refresh is not an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was due to Zend cache. Can be fixed by disabling it on Apache

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable=0
opcache.enable_cli=0
```